# Can we reopen this question as a special case?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1291377/124466) is about installing Ubuntu on a mac with M1 processor, and it was marked as a duplicate of [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu). The answer to that question is open ended, and says "try it out".

Unfortunately, most of us don't know how to even "Try Ubuntu" on the new mac due to its new (and closed) architecture. A lot of people may be interested in running Ubuntu on it. That's why I suggest we reopen this question until someone finds a solution.

Why I want to reopen this despite the current answer being "no, you can't": people are [working](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2020/12/apple-silicon-linux-support-project) on it, and the answer may change in near future.

Comment: The question is re-opened now and you can answer it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question was reopened by the community and a moderator, but I'm going to put my two cents into this with my mod hat on.

The question of "Can I install Ubuntu on X" remains answered at the core duplicate question of [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu) and should probably still be closed **as a duplicate of that**.  The accepted answer and community wiki there can be amended with the content of my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1303897/10616):

> The answer to this question comes from Linus Torvalds himself - put
> simply, it's a "no".  But more specifically:
>
> > The main problem with the M1 for me is the GPU and other devices around it, because that's likely what would hold me off using it
> > because it wouldn't have any Linux support unless Apple opens up...
> > [that] seems unlikely, but hey, you can always hope.
> >
> > <sub>Source: https://www.zdnet.com/article/linus-torvalds-would-like-to-use-an-m1-mac-for-linux-but/ - an Interview with Linus by ZDNet</sub>
>
> The core problem here is that the Linux kernel itself does not support
> the M1, and without core Linux support in the core Linux kernel for M1
> chips and architectures and devices, there is not going to be a way to
> install Ubuntu.  And without Apple releasing information on the
> support for the chipset and such, it will not likely see any Linux
> support in the future.
>
> Purportedly, there [are developers working on supporting the M1
> chip](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2020/12/apple-silicon-linux-support-project)
> however there is NO eta on this, and unless Apple starts releasing
> more information and code for their chipsets it's likely to take A
> Long Time.  And until such support is figured out through the 'trial
> and error' approach to code hacking and developing support and such,
> there is no way to install Ubuntu (or any Linux variant) on M1 chips.

... with the above text being added to an "M1 Chips on Apple Hardware" subsection.

I don't personally agree as a moderator with the reopening - edge cases like this are easy to fix on the canonical question and should be done, rather than reopening a single post simply to say "No, it won't be supported".

Answer (score 1):

Why does it need reopening? Just add an M1 case to the community wiki answer on the dupe. If there were actually some documented special method, sure, it would be worth reopening and posting as an answer, but if the answer is just "no, you can't at the moment", then I don't see a need for a separate post.

Comment: In my opinion, "no you can't" is only half an answer. Explanation on why not would be a full answer. Also, another reason I prefer to reopen the question, I expect a lot of users in the future would be asking about this when more people will be interested in getting the new Mac with the M1 chip. Having a dedicated q&a for that will make the google search results a lot more efficient for users. If users unfamiliar with how SE works find an answer that says "TRY IT OUT" in large font, they will most likely not go through an answer that long.

Comment: Meh, installation on recent Apple devices have been broken for years now (ever since the T2 encryption thing, the internal SSD couldn't be detected on new MBPs, for example). Does it matter what the specific reason for breakage is on $RANDOM_APPLE_DEVICE? Because even if the new M1 chip GPUs were supported, would the T2 chips (or whatever the new equivalent is) be? Or something else will be broken

Comment: And here is the special method. https://corellium.com/blog/linux-m1

Comment: @Arch ok, so post the answer, why comment here?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with this, as the answer to this question is a pretty straightforward "no".

Since the Linux kernel will not support it in the near future based on Linus' feedback.

And then link it in the main answer of the duplicate under a new "M1" section.
I voted to reopen the question, you can answer it if enough people agree with reopening it.